# Scheme: overload built-in procedures, general overloading

Tags: scheme, overloading

More specifically, can you overload the built-in Scheme procedure display?

More generally, how can you overload any procedure in Scheme?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scheme doesn't have overloading based on types a`la Java/C++, it's dynamically typed so it wouldn't make sense.

You can do a few things though:

You can overload based on the structure of the arguments:

```
(define overload1
    (case-lambda
        ((x y) (+ x y))
        ((x y z) (+ (- x y) z))))
```

This doesn't really help you though since `display` is only going to take one argument no matter what.

```
(define (overload-kinda x)
    (cond
        ((list? x) (do-list x))
        ((symbol? x) (do-sym x))
        ;etc
        ))
```

Which is hacky but sometimes necessary.

My usual approach is higher order functions and the case lambda

```
(define my-display
    (case-lambda
        ((x) (display x))
        ((x f) (display (f x)))))
```

Now if we need special treatment for displaying anything we pass in a function to render it.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer don't overload the function, only define different function with same behavior.

Scheme usually allow to overwrite bultin function, so to overload the function (e.g. `display`) you can use something called [Monkey Patch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch):

```lisp
(define display (let ((orig display))
                  (lambda (x . rest)
                     (let ((port (if (null? rest)
                                     (current-output-port)
                                     (car rest))))
                       (if (number? x)
                           (orig (string-append "#<" (number->string x 16) ">") port)
                           (orig x port))))))
```

and now the display work differently with numbers. you can also use custom types like display different type of records in specific way. This is general example how to overwrite bultin function in any language that allow to modify the original binding. You save original function in variable, redefine the function and if you what to call original function you use the variable where you saved original.

The code can be abstracted away into general macro that will redefine the function and run your code on specific types of arguments, so it would be proper overloading like in Java and not only based on number of arguments like in `case-lambda`.

Here is example such macro (using lisp type macro):

```lisp
(define-macro (overload name-spec . body)
   (let ((name (car name-spec))
         (args (cdr name-spec)))
      `(define ,name (let ((,name ,name))
                       (lambda ,args
                          ,@body)))))

(overload (display x . rest)
   (let ((port (if (null? rest)
                   (current-output-port)
                   (car rest))))
     (if (number? x)
         (display (string-append "#<" (number->string x 16) ">") port)
         (display x port))))

(display 10)
;; ==> #<a>
(display "20")
;; ==>  20
```