# How can I attach a type tag to a closure in Scheme?

Tags: oop, object, scheme

How can I attach an arbitrary tag to a closure in Scheme?

Here are a couple things I'd like to use this for:

(1) To mark closures that provide an interface to produce a string for what they represent, like what [@kud0h](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2053774/kud0h) asked for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15892214). A general `->string` procedure could include code something like this:

```
(display (if (stringable? x)
             (x 'string)
             x)
         str-port)
```

(2) More generally, to determine if a closure is an "object" that obeys the rules of a general object interface, or maybe to tell the class of an object (something like what [@KPatnode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2062731/kpatnode) was asking about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16051518/using-let-variables-in-a-lambda-in-scheme/16053212#16053212)).

I can't query a procedure to see if it supports a certain interface by calling it, because if it doesn't support a known interface, calling the procedure will produce unpredictable results, most likely a run-time error.

[Chez Scheme](http://www.scheme.com/csug8/objects.html#./objects:s60) has `putprop` and `getprop` procedures that allow you to add keys and values to symbols. However, closures can be anonymous, or bound to different symbols, so I'd prefer to attach a calling-convention tag to the closure itself, not a symbol that it's bound to.

The only idea I have right now is to maintain a global hash table of all "stringable" or "object" closures in the system. That seems a little clunky. Is there a simpler, more elegant, or more efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Racket has [applicable structures](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/private/base..rkt%29._prop~3aprocedure%29%29): you can give a structure type an apply hook to be called if an instance is used as a function.

If you want a more portable solution, you can use a hash table to associate your data with certain procedures. Unless your Scheme provides weak hashtables, though, keep in mind that the hashtable will prevent the procedures from being garbage-collected.

Comment: Thanks. I had not heard of applicable structures, but that does indeed sound like a very straightforward way to attach a procedure to some data without creating a mess when calling the procedure. I'm using Chez Scheme, which has weak references, but that might be a moot point if this can only be done in Racket (or some other extension of Scheme).

Answer (score 0):

I think you might, instead of tagging procedures per se, want to look at [Racket's object system](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/classes.html), which has a concept of interfaces. It sounds quite similar to what you're after.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, I'm really interested in making objects with defined interfaces that are respected by the language. Racket's object system might be just what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could go extreme and redefine `lambda` syntax.  Something like this (but untested by me):

```
(define *properties* '())    ;; example only

(define-syntax lambda
  (let-syntax ((sys-lambda
                (syntax-rules ()
                  ((_ args body ...)
                   (lambda args body ...)))))
    (syntax-rules ()
      ((_ args body ...)
       (let ((func (sys-lambda args body ...)))
         (set! *properties*
               (cons (cons func '(NO-PROPERTIES))
                     *properties*))
         func)))))
```

Comment: Indeed a macro provides a syntactically nice way to make attaching the property convenient. I was thinking of `λo` to mean "object lambda". As for how to how to attach the property to the procedure, it looks like you're also thinking of a global variable bound to a list (or hash table) of object procedures. Is this really the best that Scheme offers?

Comment: a) It does not need to be global nor a property list; hence 'example only'.  b) Scheme, by design, is meant to be a minimal language that allows one to explore programming concepts. c) there is TinyClos, a Scheme implementation of the Common Lisp Object System more or less.